# How to perform under sampling in scikit learn?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dataset, scikit-learn, sampling

We have a retinal dataset wherein the diseased eye information constitutes 70 percent of the information whereas the non diseased eye constitutes the remaining 30 percent.We want a dataset wherein the diseased as well as the non diseased samples should be equal in number. Is there any function available with the help of which we can do the same?

Answer (score 22):

I would choose to do this with [Pandas `DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe) and [`numpy.random.choice`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html). In that way it is easy to do random sampling to produce equally sized data-sets. An example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(7, 4))
data['Healthy'] = [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

This data has two non-healthy and five healthy samples. To randomly pick two samples from the healthy population you do:

```
healthy_indices = data[data.Healthy == 1].index
random_indices = np.random.choice(healthy_indices, 2, replace=False)
healthy_sample = data.loc[random_indices]
```

To automatically pick a subsample of the same size as the non-healthy group you can do:

```
sample_size = sum(data.Healthy == 0)  # Equivalent to len(data[data.Healthy == 0])
random_indices = np.random.choice(healthy_indices, sample_size, replace=False)
```

Comment: Please do correct me if i'm wrong, but to pick a subsample of the same size as the non healthy group after picking the healthy group, wouldnt it be: `
not_healthy = df[df.Healthy == 0].index
random_indices = np.random.choice(not_healthy, sum(data['healthy']), replace=False)
renew_sample = data.loc[random_indices]`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `np.random.choice` for a naive under sampling as suggested previously, but an issue can be that some of your random samples are very similar and thus misrepresents the data set.

A better option is to use the [imbalanced-learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn) package that has multiple options for balancing a dataset. A good tutorial and description of these can be found [here](https://www.kaggle.com/rafjaa/resampling-strategies-for-imbalanced-datasets).

The package lists a few good options for under sampling (from their github):

> - Random majority under-sampling with replacement
> - Extraction of majority-minority Tomek links
> - Under-sampling with Cluster Centroids
> - NearMiss-(1 & 2 & 3)
> - Condensed Nearest Neighbour
> - One-Sided Selection
> - Neighboorhood Cleaning Rule
> - Edited Nearest Neighbours
> - Instance Hardness Threshold
> - Repeated Edited Nearest Neighbours
> - AllKNN

Answer (score 2):

As a variant you can use stochastic method. Assume, you have got a dataset `data` which is a big number of tuples `(X, Y)`, where `Y` is diseased eye information (0 or 1). You can prepare a wrapper for your dataset, which passes all non diseased eyes and passes diseased eyes with probability 0.3 / 0.7 (you need only 30% of diseased eyes from the dataset).

```
from random import random


def wrapper(data):
    prob = 0.3 / 0.7

    for X, Y in data:
        if Y == 0:
            yield X, Y
        else:
            if random() < prob:
                yield X, Y


# now you can use the wrapper to extract needed information
for X, Y in wrapper(your_dataset):
    print X, Y
```

Be careful, if you need to use this wrapper as a generator many times and want to have  identical results, you have to set fixed random seed before using the function `random()`. More about it: https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html